# nested logical expression test in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a one-liner as a replacement for the below snippet.

```
# Check to see if the database is online; exit if not
isbooted=`grep 'Current state: Booted' serverlog.log | wc -l`
if [ $isbooted -eq 0 ]
then
   exit 
fi 

# Check to see if the database has crashed; exit if so
iscrashed=`grep 'Status: OK' serverlog.log | wc -l`
if [ $iscrashed -eq 0 ]
then 
   exit 
fi

echo 0
```

This is what I have done so far (I am unsure if this is correct),

```
   [ $(grep 'Current state: Booted' serverlog.log | wc -l) -eq 0 ] \
&& [ $(grep 'Status: OK' serverlog.log | wc -l) -eq 0 ]            \
&& echo 0
```

Can you please help me here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea seems ok, but I'd go with a simplified version:

```
grep -q 'Current state: Booted' serverlog.log && grep -q 'Status: OK' serverlog.log && echo 0
```

or alternatively (you can replace `-ge` with `-eq` if you expect both lines to occur exactly once):

```
[ "$(grep -c -e 'Current state: Booted' -e 'Status: OK' serverlog.log)" -ge 2 ] && echo 0
```

Both versions print 0 if `serverlog.log` contains both `'Current state: Booted'` and `Status: OK`.

For further reference see [grep(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep).

Comment: Thanks for this. If I need to echo 1 in case if my first two statements returns non-zero should I be using `|| echo 1` at the end?

Comment: If both statements return nonzero at the same time? Bear in mind that in shell logical operators have the same precedence and are left-associative (`&&` is not prioritized over `||`), see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators/89649) for details.